# ARM Template Copy function not picking values form parameter

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Hi I have created a simple ARM template to create Route table and routes, I am trying to use Copy function in properties to define  routes based on the Parameter Array.  following is the code written

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "routetablename": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "DDS-SHD-ROUTETABLE",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Route Table Name"
      }
    },
    "disableBgpRoutePropagation": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "false",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Route Propagation."
        }
    },


    "DD": {
        "type": "array",
        "defaultValue":  [
          "10.0.0.0/24",
          "10.1.0.0/24",
          "10.2.0.0/24"],
        "metadata": {
          "description": "OnPremises Address Prefix for Subnet01."
        }
    },


        "tagvalue": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Shared Network Services",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Tag Value for Resource."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "routetablename": "[parameters('routetablename')]",
    "tagvalue": "[parameters('tagvalue')]",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]"


  },
  "resources": [
    {
        "name": "[variables('routetablename')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
        "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
        "location": "[variables('location')]",
        "tags": {
        "app": "[variables('tagvalue')]"
        },
        "dependsOn": [],
        "properties": {
            "disableBgpRoutePropagation": "[parameters('disableBgpRoutePropagation')]",
        "Copy":
              [
            { 
              "name": "routes",
              "count": "[length(parameters('DD'))]",
              "input": {
                "name": "[concat('OnPrem',copyIndex('routes'))]",
                 "addressPrefix": "[parameters('DD')]",
                "nextHopType": "VirtualNetworkGateway"
              }
            }
          ]

      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As per My understanding the I sshould get 1 Route table with 3 routes namely 
Onprem0
OnPrem1
OnPrem2

Instead I get following error:

```
 "details": [
    {
      "code": "AddressPrefixStringCannotBeNullOrEmpty",
      "message": "Address prefix string for resource /subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/CAZAUSE-MGMT-NETWORK-RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/routeTables/DDS-SHD-ROUTETABLE/routes/OnPrem0 cannot be null or empty.",
      "details": []
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got this Fixed  was missing the COpyIndex() in AddressSuffix Parameter as follows

```
"Copy":
              [
            { 
              "name": "routes",
              "count": "[length(parameters('DD'))]",
              "input": {
                "name": "[concat('OnPrem-',copyIndex('routes'))]",
                "properties": {
                 "addressPrefix": "[parameters('DD')[copyIndex('routes')]]",
                "nextHopType": "VirtualNetworkGateway"
```